Is there a limitation on the size of data (Key Material) that an AWS KMS Wrapping Key can encrypt?
I have a 4096-RSA Private key that I want to use as key material in AWS KMS to generate a KMS key.
While setting up an external key in AWS KMS, it does not let us upload a Key Material directly for security reasons. It provides a Wrapping Key and we need to encrypt our Key Material with this Wrapping Key before uploading it to KMS.
To encrypt my Key Material (the 4096 RSA Private Key) with Wrapping Key, I used the following command
openssl rsautl \
    -encrypt \
    -in rsa_key_4096.pem \
    -oaep \
    -inkey WrappingPublicKey.bin \
    -pubin \
    -keyform DER \
    -out encrypted_rsa_key

Where rsa_key_4096.pem is my Key Material, WrappingPublicKey.bin is the Wrapping Key provided by KMS and encrypted_rsa_key will be the encrypted key that gets generated.
However, I ran into a limitation of data size.
RSA operation error
40382BEC01000000:error:0200006E:rsa routines:ossl_rsa_padding_add_PKCS1_OAEP_mgf1_ex:data too large for key size:crypto/rsa/rsa_oaep.c:87:

It looks like WrappingKey cannot encrypt a data size of 4096.
I'm not a sec/devops expert. Need some info on if I'm doing something wrong or if there is a workaround.
Or any suggestions on what's the best way to store private keys (AWS CloudHSM is the best option, but also expensive hence out of budget).

In general pure RSA can never encrypt anything (key or data) larger than the modulus size minus a padding-dependent amount; for RSA-4096 OAEP this is about 480 bytes, which is too small for any RSA private key (even RSA-1024, which is no longer secure or approved). See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/importing-keys-encrypt-key-material.html where the tabs for RSAES_OAEP_SHA_{1,256} both say "is not supported for RSA private keys". The tab for RSA_AES_KEY_WRAP_SHA_1 shows a hybrid encryption/wrapping that DOES support things the size of an RSA private key.

@dave_thompson_085 Thanks for the link. I got my answers
